# Создать функцию

Tags: javascript, функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Создать функцию которая принимает в параметры размеры рисуемой матрицы, например если дать 4x4 должна рисоваться такая матрица

в каждом квадрате рандомно поставить один из 3-х цветов синий, зеленый, красный, при нажатии на любую из них квадрат начинает плавно моргать меняя opacity

Вот код из но почему-то не работает:

```js
var cols = prompt('Введите количество строк', '');
var rows = prompt('Введите количество столбцов', '');
cols = parseInt(cols);
rows = parseInt(rows);
document.write('<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="1000px" height="600px">');
var color;

function getColor() {

  var min = 1,
    max = 3;
  var colorNum = Math.random() * (max) + min,
    color;
  if (colorNum == 1) {
    color = 'blue';
  }
  if (colorNum == 2) {
    color = 'green';
  }
  if (colorNum == 3) {
    color = 'red';
  }
  return color;

}
for (i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
    console.log(color);
    document.write('<td style="background-color=' + color + '"></td>');
  }
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write('</table>');
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Comment: какая матрица должна рисоваться? откуда код? почему код удалили?

Comment: код но почему-то не работает

Comment: по ссылке перейдёте тут не ставится

Comment: Нет не перейдете :) вставляйте код непосредственно в вопрос, с точным указанием что именно не работает или работает не так

Comment: ну как то так ставится

Comment: я не для рекламы мне не нужна переход по ссылке мне просто код паказать

Comment: @Tigo, перенес код в сниппет. Добавляйте описание что именно не работает, какое ожидаемое поведение и как работает сейчас

Comment: не работает рандомные 3 цвета

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) возвращает **дробное** число, соответственно любая проверка с целым числом будет возвращать `false`, а так как не назначено значения по умолчанию - `color` всегда *undefined*.

В качестве решения можно округлять значение перед сравнением, например с использованием [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Следующая ошибка: использование переменной *color*, определенной внутри функции, за пределами этой функции, вместо этого нужно вызывать саму функцию

И последняя ошибка: неверное выражение для определения случайного числа. Требуемый диапазон от 1 до 3, а значения приходят от 1 до 4.

```js
var cols = prompt('Введите количество строк', '');
var rows = prompt('Введите количество столбцов', '');
cols = parseInt(cols);
rows = parseInt(rows);
document.write('<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="1000px" height="600px">');
var color;

function getColor() {

  var min = 1,
    max = 2;
  var colorNum = Math.round(Math.random() * (max) + min),
    color;
  if (colorNum == 1) {
    color = 'blue';
  }
  if (colorNum == 2) {
    color = 'green';
  }
  if (colorNum == 3) {
    color = 'red';
  }
  console.log(colorNum);
  return color;

}
for (i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
    document.write('<td style="background-color:' + getColor() + '"></td>');
  }
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write('</table>');
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

Comment: спс очень признателен за помощь